# Showing availability from database on timetable PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a table that shows room availability for today's date.

I have a MySQL table with headings 'start_time' 'end_time' and 'date'. I need to display available timeslots in a timetable of sorts [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ16y.jpg). I have tried numerous ways of doing this but I am still missing something. I do not think I am creating an array and looping through it correctly. Below is what I have so far:

```
<?php

    define('DB_NAME', 'database');
    define('DB_USER', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$conn) {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
         }
    else { echo "Connected"; };


$roomsAvailability = 'SELECT start_time, end_time FROM room_booking WHERE date = CURDATE()';
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $roomsAvailability);

if(! $retval ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$times = ['9:00','9:30', '10:00', '10:30',  '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00',
        '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30', '20:00'];

?> 

<style>
table, th, td {
    margin:5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.available {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>B-12</th><th>G.05</th><th>G.06</th><th>1.04</th><th>1.05</th><th>1.06</th><th>2.04</th><th>2.05</th><th>2.06</th><th>3.04</th><th>3.05</th><th>3.06</th></tr>

<?php

foreach($times as $time)
{
?>
    <tr>
    <?php
        echo "<td>$time</td>";
        foreach($roomsAvailability as $room) => $roomsAvailability)
        {
            if(in_array($time , $roomsAvailability))
            {
                echo "<td class='available'>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='notAvailable'>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }

    ?>
    </tr>
<?php

}


?>
</table>
```

Can anyone can see what I am doing wrong here? I am getting the error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

If any one can spot what I am doing wrong or knows of a better way to do this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach is not defined correctly.

`foreach($roomsAvailability as $room) => $roomsAvailability)`

As per : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

`foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of errors in your code,

First you need to fetch the data as array before executing in foreach

```
$roomsAvailability = 'SELECT start_time, end_time FROM room_booking WHERE date = CURDATE()';
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $roomsAvailability);
$results = array();
// fetch all records with while loop
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Then your foreach syntax error it should be

```
foreach($results as $room => $roomsAvailability)
{
    if(in_array($time , $roomsAvailability))
    {
      ---
    }
}
```

Note: $results is `mysqli_fetch_array` value [mysql fetch array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

[foreach syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thank you for that. Now that I have applied the correct syntax it is giving me the error:   in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given - does this mean there is an issue with the array data in my database?

Comment: I have printed the results of the array and it seems to only be getting the first row i.e. two results (start_time and end_time)

Comment: @A.B I have edited my answer please check, You need to use `while` loop to execute with all records. Hope it works

Comment: I am now receiving the error - Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @A.B array_values() is not there in your code, and yours in_array should be `in_array($time, $row)`  not `$results`

Answer (score 0):

First, the error lies in the section given below

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $roomsAvailability);
if(! $retval ) { --- }
```

You did not tell php what to do with the resource_id that was returned by mysqli_query() function. It will always return true for the if statement, till the function returns a resource_id.

Secondly, Your foreach is incorrect. You statement is

```
foreach($roomsAvailability as $room) => $roomsAvailability)
```

The syntax for foreach is

```
foreach($_your_variable as $_new_variable)
```

Or you can use the below given syntax, if you are interested in fetching the index as well as the value stored in that index.

```
foreach($_your_variable as $_index => $_value)
```

you can assign any variable name instead of $_index and $_value.

Third, the variable $roomsAvailability contains the sql string. So you cannot access it as mysql resource. You should use mysqli_fetch_object(), mysqli_fetch_array() or mysqli_fetch_assoc() on $retval since it contains the valid resource_id of the mysql query. The code could have been like the one below

`$roomsAvailability = 'SELECT start_time, end_time FROM room_booking WHERE date = CURDATE()';`

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $roomsAvailability);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval);

foreach($result as $row){
--Your Statements-- 
}
```